# Acpi PCC Probe failed message during bootup

Tags: acpi

0.6470901 ACPI PCC probe failed. 
This is the message which I get while booting up.
I really love the Distro because of it's GUI but it is causing me way too many problems.
Can someone please help me.
UPDATE: I read about a software called [Boot Repairs.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)
Will it be helpful in solving the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just ignore the message if your PC boots correctly. I also get this message on all distros. If you computer doesn't boot it is another problem. Don't down vote this because your PC doesn't boot since that is not related to this harmless message

Comment: The screen freezes with that message. And I am forced to manually restart the computer by pressing the CPU button. Should I continue doing that.

Comment: @A-ubuntu what's the CPU button

Comment: there are two buttons on my CPU. One is power button and another is for 'restart'. I press the restart one in this case.

Comment: Also, Can the boot repairs software help me? link in the question above.

Comment: @A-ubuntu Does the live USB / CD work. Also when you mean CPU to you mean your PC case

Comment: Yes USB / CD works and yes i refer to the PC Case

Comment: @A-ubuntu What did you do last?

Comment: As i told you above i manually restarted the computer 3 times and finally it booted up normally and i haven't shut it off since.

Comment: @A-ubuntu What did you install last? Don't power off your PC forcefully instead use http://www.howtogeek.com/119127/use-the-magic-sysrq-key-on-linux-to-fix-frozen-x-servers-cleanly-reboot-and-run-other-low-level-commands/ because force shutdown creates bad sectors on you hard drive

Comment: I booted with a live CD to partition with Gparted and I increased the size of my / directory.

Comment: @A-ubuntu Why?.

Comment: While switching from Ubuntu to Elementary OS I wrongly partitioned my hard drive and I wanted to use the unallocated space to be used in / directory.
Did that cause the issue?

Comment: @A-ubuntu When did you install your system and has it worked correctly before

Comment: I was using Ubuntu for the last 4 months and it was working perfectly.
But i liked elementary OS so i decided to switch to it and it has been three days since I installed this OS.

Comment: @A-ubuntu did it ever not give the error

Comment: But according to the threads that I read it wasn't supposed to give any.

Comment: @A-ubuntu I am talking about not booting not the message

Comment: What should I do now will the Boot Repair help me??

Comment: @A-ubuntu maybe